# When is the latest I can consume the Umbilical Cords?

Tags: bloodborne

In order to get the "true ending" of the game, I have to consume at least three One Third of Umbilical Cords and make the right choice before the final boss fight, but **when is the latest possible time I can consume these to unlock the final ending?** Does it have to be before I make my choice or can it be any time before I deliver the final blow?

Comment: And this just has to end up in Hot Network Questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the third ending in the game you need to consume 3 coords before the fight against *Gehrman, The First Hunter*, ends.

So anytime before Gehrman dies will still unlock the third ending.